# How can google advertisement ID can help developer in advertising/monetizing their apps?

Tags: android, google-play, google-advertising-id

It's said that "The advertising ID is a unique, user-resettable ID for advertising, provided by Google Play services. It gives users better controls and provides developers with a simple, standard system to continue to monetize their apps."
in https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6048248?hl=en

But i need more information about google advertisement ID. How can this advertisement ID specifically help developer in advertising/monetizing their apps? Do developers able to get some information about the user from google by using user's google advertisement ID? or does this ID only helps developer to identify the user's advertisement so that developer can build their own tracking database about the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use advertising ID you can track users which usually result in better targeted Ads and higher click rate on ads, which means more expensive ads and more revenue.

When you give an Ad network the AD_ID they can track the user across multiple apps and websites and build a profile for the user depending on their interests and needs.

You can **NOT** get any info from AD_ID by itself, but it helps you track the user.

Anyway I recommend not depending on AD_ID because it will become not effective soon because users can opt out of it and most of users will choose not to be tracked.

> As part of Google Play services update in late 2021, the advertising ID will be removed when a user opts out of personalization using advertising ID in Android Settings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just want to confirm this line "You can NOT get any info from AD_ID by itself, but it helps you track the user.", through what I understand, this ID helps me by identifying the user right? it's like giving a name to a entity?